# Looking for proof of formula in WolframMathWorld article

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, analytic-number-theory

I came across the formula (24) in the WolframMathWorld article on Web page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAngles.html where no source of the proof could be
identified by me.

The formula is $$\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor}\sin(\frac{k\pi}{n})=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}}$$

I am near a proof but it is rather intricate and maybe awkward and much to complicated.

Does anybody know the source of the original proof or is there an elementary homework-style one without deeper necessary experience ?